# What is difference between `this` and `base` in the following statement?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor

What is the difference between `this` and `base` key function in  following statements?

```
public Customer(string name, string referrerName) : base(name)

public Customer(string Name) : this(Name)
```

Answer (score 8):

`base(name)` will call the parent class constructor with supplied argument

`this(name)` will call current class constructor with supplied argument which in your case is current constructor and gives you a compile error because a constructor can not call itself.

assume you have these classes

```
public class A
{
    public A(string a) { Console.WriteLine(a); }
    public A(int a) { Console.WriteLine(a * a); }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(string a): base (a) { }
    public B(int a): this (a.ToString()) { }
}
```

`new B("hello")` will call `public A(string a)` and print "hello" in output

`new B(4)` will call `public B(string a)` which will call `public A(string a)` and print "4" in output

Answer (score 0):

```
public Customer(string name, string referrerName) : base(name)
```

when Customer constructor called the base constructor also called, the second example not make sense it's look like the constructor call itself...

Comment: contractor? maybe constructor?